# Bootstrap-t Method for Comparing Trimmed Means in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, hypothesis-test, robust

I am confused with different robust methods to compare independent means. I found good explanation in statistical textbooks. For example `yuen()` in case of equal sample sizes. My samples are rather unequal, thus I would like to try a bootstrap-t method (from Wilcox book: Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing, p.163). It says `yuenbt()` would be a possible solution.

But all textbooks say I can use vectors here:

```
yuenbt(x,y,tr=0.2,alpha=0.05,nboot=599,side=F)
```

If I check the local description it says:

```
yuenbt(formula, data, tr = 0.2, nboot = 599)
```

What's wrong with my trial:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(5,6,12,30,2,2,3,65)
yuenbt(x,y)
```

Why can't I use yuenbt-function with my two vectors? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the help (for those wondering, `yuenbt` is from the package `WRS2`...) for `yuenbt`, it takes a formula and a dataframe as arguments. My impression is that it expects data in long format.

With your example data, we can achieve that like so:

```
library(WRS2)

x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(5,6,12,30,2,2,3,65)

dat <- data.frame(value=c(x,y),group=rep(c("x","y"), c(length(x),length(y))))
```

We can then use the function:

```
yuenbt(value~group, data=dat)
```

Comment: Might there have been a change from the package WRS? I don't have profound knowledge about packages documentation. But those textbooks work with vectors ...

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with the package but just downloaded it to see and try to answer your question. Textbooks with code can become outdated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your coding :) Now I can work on my interpretation of my bootstraping